# Why does Chrome prevent my Mac from sleeping?

Tags: sleep-wake, google-chrome

I don't mean browsing the Internet is preventing us from sleeping, that's obvious. I've disabled [Safe Sleep](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/08/22/why-hibernate-or-safe-sleep-mode-is-no-longer-necessary-in-os/) to reduce sleep times from 20 seconds to 2, but Chrome doesn't want to play nicely.

Here's the log with Chrome:

```
15/07/12 1:19:07.975 PM LogMeInGUI[350]: String:WEBSVC|OFFLINE
15/07/12 1:19:13.992 PM WindowServer[75]: Created shield window 0x478 for display 0x04272e80
15/07/12 1:19:13.993 PM WindowServer[75]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x0(0)
15/07/12 1:19:13.000 PM kernel[0]: PM notification timeout (pid 3469, Google Chrome He)
15/07/12 1:19:13.000 PM kernel[0]: PM notification timeout (pid 3474, Google Chrome He)
15/07/12 1:19:14.025 PM WindowServer[75]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x0(0)
15/07/12 1:19:14.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
15/07/12 1:19:20.346 PM WindowServer[75]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: no action for lock state 1
15/07/12 1:19:20.000 PM kernel[0]: Wake reason: EC LID0
15/07/12 1:19:20.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
15/07/12 1:19:20.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::checkInterfacePowerState: Check _pwrOffThreadCall!
15/07/12 1:19:20.000 PM kernel[0]: HID tickle 1 ms
15/07/12 1:19:20.000 PM kernel[0]: Previous Sleep Cause: 5
```

And without:

```
15/07/12 1:20:39.514 PM WindowServer[75]: Created shield window 0x48d for display 0x04272e80
15/07/12 1:20:39.514 PM WindowServer[75]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x0(0)
15/07/12 1:20:39.545 PM WindowServer[75]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x0(0)
15/07/12 1:20:40.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
15/07/12 1:20:47.351 PM WindowServer[75]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: no action for lock state 1
15/07/12 1:20:47.000 PM kernel[0]: Wake reason: EC LID0
15/07/12 1:20:47.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
15/07/12 1:20:47.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::checkInterfacePowerState: Check _pwrOffThreadCall!
15/07/12 1:20:47.000 PM kernel[0]: HID tickle 1 ms
15/07/12 1:20:47.000 PM kernel[0]: Previous Sleep Cause: 5
```

These lines from the Google Chrome Helper are the reason:

```
15/07/12 1:19:13.000 PM kernel[0]: PM notification timeout (pid 3469, Google Chrome He)
15/07/12 1:19:13.000 PM kernel[0]: PM notification timeout (pid 3474, Google Chrome He)
```

What does that mean?

This is a relevant question: [Why does my MacBook Pro take so long to go to sleep?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/why-does-my-macbook-pro-take-so-long-to-go-to-sleep)

Deja vu: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1112715

Answer (score 1):

[Chrome Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs/) seems to fix it.