# Fans go wild when screensaver is active - MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I found a similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86299/16gb-of-ram-makes-macbook-pros-fans-go-wild-before-sleep), but it's related to the laptop preparing for sleep. My settings while connected to power are:

- Screensaver after 20 minutes
- Turn screen off after 1 hour

I assume that my laptop won't sleep until after the screen has turned off - is this accurate? If so, any other indications as to why my fans go into hyper-drive when the screensaver turns on?

Comment: Which screensaver is it? One bundled with macOS or a third-party screensaver?

Comment: Yeah it's packaged with MacOS -- arabesque

Comment: Have you checked fan's rpm with an app like iStatistica or 'Mac Fan Control'?

Answer (score 2):

My fanspeed also was incredibly high when on OSX stock screensaver. Some virus scans and resetting of the MacBooks PRAM and VRAM later, I did a check and graphed the cpu usage. It was indeed the screensaver process which kept cpu at 100%.
It was set to a transition of pictures in a folder. **Apparently the fade and float effect is too much for the mac. Switch to a blank screen with a clock shown.** Fan speed went down to non audible since then and CPU is as low as can be during screensaver now.