# Why does my iMac take so long to go to sleep?

Tags: macos, imac, sleep-wake

**Note:** I have seen [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53/why-does-my-macbook-pro-take-so-long-to-go-to-sleep) question as well as [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/why-does-my-macbook-pro-take-so-long-to-go-to-sleep) question, I don't believe that either pertain to this situation.

---

When I press the sleep button on my iMac it consistently takes 30-31 seconds to go to sleep. The computer is reasonably old, it is a early 2008 model and because of this, the hard drive is pretty full (only about 2GB left). When the computer sleeps there are no processes taking up a lot of CPU and most of the RAM is available. The computer wakes up reasonably quickly (1-2 seconds)

I would like to know why the computer takes so long to go to sleep, and if there is a solution to the problem.

Here are the stats of the computer:

OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)

2GB DDR2 SDRAM

2.8 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

If anymore information is needed, just add a comment.

**Edit:**

Here is the console output when I put the computer to sleep.

```
8/20/14 11:58:36 AM kernel  PM notification timeout (pid 199, DashboardClient)
8/20/14 11:58:36 AM kernel  PM notification timeout (pid 199, DashboardClient)
8/20/14 11:58:36 AM kernel  hibernate image path: /var/vm/sleepimage
8/20/14 11:58:36 AM kernel  sizeof(IOHibernateImageHeader) == 512
8/20/14 11:58:36 AM kernel  Opened file /var/vm/sleepimage, size 2147483648,         partition base 0xc805000, maxio 400000 ssd 0
8/20/14 11:58:36 AM kernel  hibernate image major 14, minor 2, blocksize 512, pollers 5
8/20/14 11:58:36 AM kernel  hibernate_alloc_pages flags 00000000, gobbling 0 pages
8/20/14 11:58:36 AM kernel  hibernate_setup(0) took 0 ms
8/20/14 11:58:37 AM Apple80211 framework[113]   ACInterfaceGetPower called with     NULL interface
8/20/14 11:58:37 AM Apple80211 framework[113]   ACInterfaceGetPower called with NULL interface
8/20/14 11:58:37 AM configd[15] network configuration changed.
8/20/14 11:58:37 AM kernel  System SafeSleep
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  hibernate_page_list_setall start 0x25717000, 0x25728000
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  hibernate_page_list_setall time: 142 ms
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  pages 324460, wire 61471, act 103587, inact 609, spec 63, zf 3, throt 0, could discard act 88461 inact 32682 purgeable 14366 spec 23218
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  hibernate_page_list_setall found pageCount 165733
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  IOHibernatePollerOpen, ml_get_interrupts_enabled 0
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  IOHibernatePollerOpen(0)
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  writing 165142 pages
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  encryptEnd 73c9a20
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  IOPolledInterface::checkForWork[5] 0xe00002eb
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  PMStats: Hibernate write took 2552 ms
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  all time: 2552 ms, comp time: 552 ms, deco time: 0 ms, 
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  image 0, uncompressed 410402816 (100196), compressed 197517516 (48%), sum1 1a4d5b57, sum2 0
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  wired_pages_encrypted 60968, wired_pages_clear 39229, dirty_pages_encrypted 0
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  hibernate_write_image done(e00002eb)
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  sleep
```

Comment: Have you checked the log to see what your system is doing while it tries to sleep? Similarly to the second question you linked above. Not saying the solution is the same (you have a lot less RAM) but the log output might point us in the right direction.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Added, sorry for the delay but I had to figure out how to do it.

Comment: The other questions indicate that 20 to 30 seconds to enter sleep is reasonable. What happens if you make a totally new user account and reboot the Mac. If you log only in to that new empty account, how long does a sleep take?

Comment: Thanks @BitNinja but this log entry only shows 4 seconds of activity. If that's the entire log for this shutdown that's pretty fast. :)

Comment: depending on how many RAM you have and how many Processes, Tasks and Apps (spcially if you have installed OSX Server App) are running its normal to take up to 2min case all these Running stuff all the Stuff currently in Ram needs to be persist (written fown) to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your full hard drive could be a reason. Some space is needed for swap and sleepimages and whatnot, and OS X has difficulties operating when it only has so little space free for those tasks. Try freeing some space (at least 5GB is recommended by Apple if I recall, I'd try to free more just to try).